# Preg_match_all and html tags

Tags: php, html, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to get the content between `<b>Author:</b>` and `<br>` from the HTML below with `preg_match_all` function however it keeps returning empty arrays. I need the middle-line HTML output, please help me.

Here's the text:

```
<b>Author:</b> <a href="http://link.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Name</a><br />
```

Here's the script I use:

```
preg_match_all("'<b>Author:</b> ([^<]*)<br />'", $page, $preg_author);
$author = $preg_author[1]; 
print_r($preg_author);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your regexp can't work you're looking for ([^<]*) basically this will fail when it will encounter the `<a` tag you should try this one

```
preg_match_all("'<b>Author:</b> (.*(?=<br />))'", $page, $preg_author);
```

basically it will catch any character (no newline) until it will encounter a 
 tag